# Getting rid of black vertical and horizontal lines

Tags: python, opencv

I want to get rid of the black vertical and horizontal lines in my image. This is the code I've written until now

```
#convert RGB to grayscale
gray_slide = cv.cvtColor(slide_ds, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#remove black areas
gray_slide[np.where(gray_slide<=[10])] = [255]

#remove edges
linek = np.zeros((11,11),dtype=np.uint8)
linek[5,...]=1
x=cv.morphologyEx(gray_slide, cv.MORPH_OPEN, linek ,iterations=1)
gray_slide+=x
```

But it doesn't do the job. 
I want this image

[image: before]

to be converted to this

[image: after]

Can you help me please?
BTW this was the original image
[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1nU6.jpg)

Comment: you can try the following: Create a mask of everything that is not pure white. Erode this mask. set every pixel that is not masked to pure white.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a way to use vertical and horizontal edge detection and then eliminate the detected areas?

Comment: try lineSegmentDetector. But probably any edge based solution will be hard to parametrize since the blobs have an edge-like border, too.

Comment: Yes that would detect the blob edges too...

Comment: do you have access to the original images without jpeg compression? Do you have access to the process that creates the black mask in the original image? it looks easier to work on the original image (even with jpeg artifacts and maybe interpolated border) than on your input image.

Answer (score 2):

Inpainting ([OpenCV docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_photo/py_inpainting/py_inpainting.html)) is one way to do this.

```
>>> img = cv2.imread("blacklines.jpg")
>>> mask = cv2.imread("blacklines_MASK.jpg", 0)
>>> dst = cv2.inpaint(img, mask, 4, cv2.INPAINT_TELEA) # you can fiddle with the parameters
>>> cv2.imwrite("dst.jpg", dst) # save the image
```

Original image:

[image: Original image]

Partial mask drawn by hand for demonstration purposes:

[image: Mask]

Final result:

[image: Final]

Now, if you want to do this programmatically for multiple images, you should consider programmatically creating masks. One approach to that is to filter images according to pixel values (e.g. what it seems you're doing with your `gray_slide`).

Edit: I tried fiddling with a few parameters myself, and it comes close, but not quite there yet...

```
>>> mask = np.zeros(gray.shape)
>>> mask[np.where(gray<=140)] = [255]
>>> cv2.imwrite('mask.jpg', mask)
True
>>> mask = cv2.imread("mask.jpg", 0)
>>> i = cv2.inpaint(img, mask, 25, cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)
>>> cv2.imwrite("i2.jpg", i)
True
```

New mask (dropping the threshold to 120 seemed better since it did not touch the inner areas, but I kept this version instead):

[image: newmask]

Result, still some black elements here and there:

[image]

In the end, if you reach the mask stage I've shown above, you just need to make those lines "wider". It is worth a try (maybe use dilation/erosion or something).

Comment: Thank you. yes since there is more than 1000 images, it has to be done programmatically. I filtered the image with this command:
gray_slide[np.where(gray_slide<=[10])] = [255]
But no matter how much I increase the parameter, the lines don't seem to disappear

Comment: @MaryamS I've added a few more stuff. I think it is quite close, and that if you experiment you will make it. Good luck!